# how to open up a small input box on eclipse using a JButton

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton, windowbuilder

how do I use a JButton to open up an input box where I would be able to paste text and possibly include another button within that mini window? would I have to create a new class or can I create it within the class I already have?

sorry if I sound confusing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JOptionPane.  Use a [listener](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener) for the button and check when the button gets clicked.  If it gets clicked then open a [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Here is an example:

```
JButton showDialogButton = new JButton("Text Button");
showDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What's your name?");//Note: input can be null.
  }
});
```

If this does not work for you, take a look at the [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) class or [tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ASimpleModalDialog.htm).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I now have an additional problem, I have the following code --> JOptionPane.showInputDialog("");                                           how would i get the ok button to do an action that i have code for?

Answer (score 1):

Now in the parent frame when you click the "Click me to show dialog" a dialoge pops up.

```
package experiments;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CreateDialogFromOptionPane {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame parent = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton();

        button.setText("Click me to show dialog!");
        parent.add(button);
        parent.pack();
        parent.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent,
                        "What is your name?", null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the other button in the mini window to do. If you just want to paste text and return that text with an OK button, you can call JOptionPane.showInputDialog() from your original button's action listener. If you want functionality beyond that, you should create a custom class that extends JDialog and add the controls and functionality you need.